# Presto Query HIVE Table Exception: Failed to list directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto

I'm new to Presto. I have two machine for presto 0.160, one is coordinator, the other is worker. I want to query table in hive. Now I can "show tables", "desc tablename", but when I want to "select * from tablename", exception occured: "Query 20170728_123013_00011_q4s3a failed: Failed to list directory: hdfs://cdh-test/user/hive/warehouse/employee_hive"

```
presto> desc hive.default.employee_hive;


Column    |  Type   | Comment 
-------------+---------+---------
 eid         | integer |         
 name        | varchar |         
 salary      | varchar |         
 destination | varchar |         
(4 rows)

Query 20170728_123001_00010_q4s3a, FINISHED, 2 nodes
Splits: 2 total, 2 done (100.00%)
0:00 [4 rows, 268B] [40 rows/s, 2.68KB/s]

presto> select * from hive.default.employee_hive;

Query 20170728_123013_00011_q4s3a, FAILED, 1 node
Splits: 1 total, 0 done (0.00%)
0:00 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]

Query 20170728_123013_00011_q4s3a failed: Failed to list directory: hdfs://cdh-test/user/hive/warehouse/employee_hive
```

Here is my configuration for hive catalog:

```
connector.name=hive-cdh4
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://***:9083
hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

where am I wrong?

Comment: nothing wrong  it may be some temporary issue ... run it again.

Answer (score 0):

The path that the table is stored on needs to exist on HDFS for Presto to open it successfully. From the path it appears your table is an "internal" hive table, meaning hive should have created the path itself. Since it hasn't, you could create it yourself using a command similar to `hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://cdh-test/user/hive/warehouse/employee_hive`, although the exact command depends on your HDFS set up.

Answer (score -1):

you can't access the hadoop directory directory. I hope you have created the table as textfile and it stores internal directory of respective user.

you just create table as external table and you can able to access via presto

```
Create External Table tablename (columnames datatypes) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;

load data inpath 'Your_hadoop_directory' into table tablename;
```

else you just create a internal table and load it to external ORC table and access via presto

```
Create Table tablename (columnames datatypes) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;

load data inpath 'Your_hadoop_directory' into table tablename;

Create external Table tablename (columnames datatypes) STORED AS ORC;

insert into orc_tablename select * from internal_tablename
```

I solved above issue by creating ORC table.